# UITableView contetOffset and swipe starting point not working together

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm using the following code in a button tap to move my table view up, but when the user swipes the table view down it gets to the original place. How can I solve it?

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0 options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                     animations:^{
                         self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 59);
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         if (finished) {
                             self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 59);
                         }
                     }
     ];
```

Any tips?

Comment: Are you using a UITableViewController?

Comment: Why not just use: `[self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 59) animated:YES];` Ditching the animation block altogether.

Comment: code updated. still bugged. if the user scroll down it does not bounce at the 59. it bounces in 0.

Answer (score 0):

They might have changed this in newer iOS releases, but I remember that UITableViewController doesn't play well with a custom defined tableView frame.

I'm pretty sure it will work correctly if you use a regular UIViewController.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the syntax; but you should be able to define your own custom gesture.  Which will handle a particular function. It should allow you to actually create your own event handler and view.

Which should allow you to control how it scrolls throughout to the position.

The article is here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizers/GestureRecognizers.html

If I'm misunderstanding what your trying to accomplish I apologize, hopefully this helps though.  If not I'm sure a more seasoned developer will be able to assist you.